# jsp error int cannot converted to boolean

Tags: jsp

i want to print just the same integer

```
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.lang.System"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Type Casting 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
int hasil = 10;
 for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
     if (hasil=i);
     out.println (i);
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

it says int cannot converted to boolean in jsp, do you have better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `==` in if instead of `=`

what you are doing is, you are assigning the value of `i` instead of comparing with `hasil`

Comment: Since `jsp` pages are internally converted to `java` files, you can't use javascript syntax here, if I am not wrong.

Comment: please accept the answer if it serves the question correctly. :)